# Convergence of iterative method

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

Assume that iterative method:
$x_{k+1}=F(x_{k})$
  where $(k=0,\,1,\,2,\,...)$
converges to $\alpha$
  which is root of $f(x)=0$
  equation.

Prove that if $F(\alpha)=\alpha$, $
  F'(\alpha)=F''(\alpha)=...=F^{(p-1)}(\alpha)=0
  $ and $ F^{(p)}(\alpha)\neq0$
  then convergence of that method is equal to $p$
 , that means:
$\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}\frac{|x_{n+1}-\alpha|}{|x_{n}-\alpha|^{p}}=C\neq0$

What's formula to calculate constant $C$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the expression $$| x_{n+1} - \alpha | = | F(x_n) - F(\alpha) |.$$

Make a Taylor expansion of $F(x_n)$ around $\alpha$ (up to the order $p$). Notice that all the terms in the expansion excepted $F(\alpha)$ and the terms with order higher than $p$ do not vanish.

Now, plug the expansion in  $| x_{n+1} - \alpha | = | F(x_n) - F(\alpha) |$ and you should only get one term on the right plus a reminder. Divide both sides by $|x_n - \alpha|^p$ and observe that the reminder term goes to $0$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$. You should now have your constant, which should look like $$ C = |F^{(p)}(\alpha)| / p! $$

Hope it helps!